How to prevent resizing snapped windows in Windows 11?
TLDR; When I have windows snapped to the left and right sides of the screen, is it possible to resize one without resizing the other?
Frequently I want to quickly have two windows on the screen, but have each take up more than 1/2 the screen.  A quick and easy way to do start is to use Windows+Left on one so it takes up the left 1/2 of the screen, then I switch to the other window I want and use Windows+Right.   Now they both take up 1/2 the screen.  After that I want to resize each of them so they cover 3/4 the screen.
What I would like to do is click just to one side of the center divider and resize one window to make it cover part of the other window, then switch to the other window and do the same.   Now they are each about 3/4 the screen size and I can see 1/4 of the other window when it's in the background and quickly switch between them.
The problem is that now with windows 11, when I try to use the edge of one window to resize it, it also resizes the other window.  To prevent this I have to minimize one of them while I resize it, then restore the other one and resize it.
Is there some setting that will disable this behavior?   I want to be able to resize each window individually without it affecting the other.
